# Can we retrieve the subscribers of an SMS opt-in message?

Tags: api, rest, mobileconnect

I can create an SMS opt-in message with the REST API. But I can't find any endpoint where I can retrieve all the numbers that have subscribed to the opt-in message.

Do we have that feature somewhere else?